# Javascript: I have a custom right-click menu but still want the spellcheck!

Tags: javascript, firefox, tinymce

I wrote a custom right-click menu thing for my website. Firefox automatically does spellchecking and underlines mis-spelled words.

However I can no longer right click on these words because I have a custom right-click menu...

Does anyone know if its possible to have code like:

```
if(needsSpellcheck) {
  //use firefox menu
} else {
  //use my menu
}
```

?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411971/firefox-if-needs-spellcheck

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution but I've read that a shift right-click will give you the firefox menu if it's overridden by a website.

Answer (score 0):

You can change spell-checking progmatically by changing the `spellcheck` attribute on an element. Just implement that in your custom context menu.